# Как запустить авто диалог в Телеграмме?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

то есть я открываю телеграмм как пользователь и бот в ТЛ мне задаёт вопрос, если я отвечаю то идет следующий вопрос. все эта цепочка вопросов у меня идет в python но когда я выгружаю в ТЛ то цепочка не запускается как сделать?

```
import time
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot("токен")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(massage):
    bot.send_message(massage.chat.id, "")


print("моя цепочка")
a = 0

while a != "89857900082":
    a = str(input("Введите 2-й номер."))
if a != "89857900082":
        print("Именно 2 номер, не 1 и не 3.")
print("Все верно!")
```

пока что мой код такой)

Comment: 1. В вашем коде бот нигде не задает вам вопрос. 2. В вашем коде нет никакой цепочки из вопросов 3. Все, что вы получаете через `input` является строкой, не нужно с помощью `str()` из строки делать строку. 4. Весь код, начиная с `print` будет выводить результат выполнения только в консоль, но не в виде ответа ботом в телеграм. 5. Что вы подразумеваете под "автодиалогом"?

Comment: Мой код 

print("text")
a = 0

while a != "89857900082":
    a = str(input("Введите 2-й номер."))
    if a != "89857900082":
        print("Именно 2 номер, не 1 и не 3.")
print("Все верно!")

 И так 17 раз цепочка в этом состоит.

в python она работает, я так понимаю в ТЛ будет. 
На счет str скорее всего, но вроде работает пусть уже стоит.
вот с 4 замечанием у меня и проблема, как сделать так чтоб работа была не только в консоли а еще и в ТЛ?
Авто диалог это цепочка, я делаю квест и хочу чтоб он был автономный.

Comment: `input` - это запрос ввода в консоли, в ТГ так не работает. Чтобы получать данные от пользователя с целью дальнейших манипуляций с ними вам необходимо ознакомиться с конечными автоматами / машиной состояний / (FSM)

Comment: Спасибо, пойду знакомиться.